# How to say Haskell operator names out loud?

Tags: haskell

Is there a convention for how to say Haskell operator names, that are only make up of symbols, out-loud?

Say I'm discussing some code with someone, for `(>>)` do I say "greater than, greater than" or "Sequentially compose two actions, discarding any value produced by the first" or something else?

Some common ones have names, eg `bind` for `(>>=)` or `fmap` for `(<$>)`.

But if I'm reading a line of code out-loud and it uses one of the many, many other operators made up of just symbols, what do I say?

Comment: I've seen `a >> b` sometimes written as ``a `andThen` b``, in some contexts.

Comment: I don't know about Haskell, but I'd use language that works best for your audience. Sometimes the "official" way is not known by the one you talk to and only increases problems.